# Wordpress Apply specific css when custom field slected

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I already add a custom field on my site. Custom field- that is a checkbox(Display Main Menu on Page).
I want when checkbox is not selected then main menu will disappears/hide.
I want to add this action when checkbox is not selected-

```
.theme-wrap{
dispaly:none !important;
}
```

PHP shortcode of my field- `<?php echo $cfs->get('display_main_menu_on_page'); ?>`

Any idea how to do that, thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean. Are you trying to make it so that when there is a checkbox you can have that CSS associated with it? Surely you can just add that to the CSS file and when it's needed it will be used, otherwise it will not be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ***think*** you're looking for a dynamically change of the class based on clicked or not for the checkbox. You could achieve this with jQuery.

Add a class `chk-box` to the checkboxes you want to be affected by this.

use jQuery by adding a specific js-file into your functions.php (for the theme):

```
function jquery_stuff() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('whatever-script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/whatever.js');
}
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_stuff');
```

Then create a filed called `whatever.js` with this content:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.chk-box', function(e) {          
        //Toggle between having the checkbox using class theme-wrap or not.
        $(this).toggleClass("theme-wrap");
    });  

});
```